# prove $C(n,k) = C(n- 2,k-2) + 2C(n-2,k-1) + C(n-2,k)$ with diagram

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Using pascals identity as reference, $C(n,k) = C(n-1,k) + C(n-1,k-1)$ when n > k +1 >.2. How to explain $C(n,k) = C(n- 2,k-2) + 2C(n-2,k-1) + C(n-2,k)$ with diagram ?

Comment: Draw a diagram with $n-2$ elements (collected together) plus $2$ more (distinct) elements. Now consider the possible ways to choose $k$ elements from the $n$, but pay particular attention to which of the last two elements are used. ... Good luck $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Also, take a look at [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)